# Wikitude app crash (poi adding problem) iPhone

Tags: ios4

I am currently working in iPhone application in which I have used wikitude api.

I am successfully integrate and run the app but my app is crash while adding  poi over wikitude  camera view. And my app throws exception of "CORE ANIMATION CALAYER NAN". I am getting this issue in iPhone 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the new version of the Wikitude iPhone API which should fix the described issue. You can download it from http://www.wikitude.org/developers

Cheers, Nicolas

Comment: Thanks I had implemented it. But sometime myapp  is  crashing at the  start of the Camera view. I had observed that if the toolbar_button image is toolbar_button_locationAccuracy_high.png image it doesnt shows any POI over the view and if i move the device then it crashes and throws the exception "CALayer Position contains [NaN 15]". But if toolbar_button  image changes to toolbar_button_locationAccuracy_middle or toolbar_button_locationAccuracy_low.png then app is not crashing.We can see all the POIs over the screen(App is working fine).
Please suggest me smthng to overcome this issue.Thanks

Comment: The Wikitude API has been updated to version 1.0.6b which should fix the issue. Please download and see if it works for you (http://www.wikitude.org/developers).